# Turn off sound effects

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to be able to turn off sound effects that I run with SKAction. This code is in my `GameScene`.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

if (//an argument) {
   let playSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("SoundDing.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
                   self.runAction(playSound)

   }
}
```

I want the button that will mute the sounds to be in my `GameStartScene`. How do I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't stop audio from playing when run from SKAction.

Use [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW2). It allows you to start, stop, pause, control volume, number of loops and other features.

Refer below posts for more Info:

- [Spritekit stopping sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431049/spritekit-stopping-sound)
- [How to stop a audio SKAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562493/how-to-stop-a-audio-skaction)
- [How to stop/cancel playSoundFileNamed in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546063/how-to-stop-cancel-playsoundfilenamed-in-swift)